# Add HTTP basic Auth to aws ec2 with Beanstalk on a Angular application

Tags: angular, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I try to add http Basic Auth on an instance of ec2 using Elastic Beanstalk. I follow this guide "http://sarahcassady.com/2016/09/18/deploy-aws-eb-app-with-auth-and-ssl/" but when i upload this is not working.

I tried to change the proxy_pass of the example for i use http://nodejs but still not working.

The worst is that i need to upload my code to make a deploy and wait all that time... You know something to improve that?

Thanks for your help

EDIT: Add the code that i used

```
# .ebextensions/01-http_basic_auth_staging.config

files:
  /etc/nginx/.htpasswd:
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      username:$apr1$k5WkOMBL$0FZNIWOLQMsHJAOREjemC/

  /etc/nginx/conf.d/staging.conf:
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        location / {
          proxy_pass        http://nodejs; 
          proxy_set_header  Host $host;
          proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
      }

  /tmp/deployment/nginx_auth.sh:
    mode: "000755"
    content: |
        sed -i 's/$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;/$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;\n   auth_basic "Restricted";\n    auth_basic_user_file \/etc\/nginx\/.htpasswd;\n/' /etc/nginx/conf.d/staging.conf


container_commands:
  01nginx_auth:
    command: "/tmp/deployment/nginx_auth.sh"
  02restart_nginx:
    command: "service nginx restart"
```

Comment: What is not working?  Can you provide some code?

Comment: You need to provide more information: (1) What is the specific error you are encountering? (2) More context about the system you are using e.g., which elastic beanstalk platform? (3) The specific configurations you are using

Comment: I edited and wrote the code. i don't see any error just that it doesn't ask for the user and password. Thanks for your help :)